# From list to pd dataframe and reshaping issue to use as target of neural network

Tags: pandas, dataframe, neural-network

I am building a simple neural network which is sequential based and train-test data are retrieved from a csv file .
There are 13 features, 15 samples and the target is any one out of five options (e.g. any color out of five colors). The 13 feature values which is used as xtrain is stored in 13 different columns which is expected. It is as follow:

```
      feat_1    feat_2    feat_3  ...   feat_11       feat_12       feat_13
0   0.090826  0.923077  0.015069  ...  0.957858      0.567030      0.526956
1   0.129642  0.910377  0.055787  ...  0.923693      0.567030      0.586102
2   0.116605  0.909931  0.000000  ...  0.884767      0.526956      0.586102
.
.
.
13  0.080155  0.919048  0.000000  ...  0.945022      0.586102      0.576427
14  0.124639  0.857820  0.279808  ...  0.937488      0.523185      0.576427

[15 rows x 13 columns] <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> (15, 13)
```

But the target (y_train) is not in different columns rather than it is one column and each y_train is saved as a list.  When it is called as y_train it looks like this:

```
0     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
.
.
13    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
14    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Name: target_comb_list, dtype: object <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> (15,) ytrain
```

When it is feed into training it shows the error:

> ValueError: A target array with shape (15, 1) was passed for an output
> of shape (None, 5) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`.

I think the problem can be solved by converting the pd.series of lists into a pd.dataframe but I was not successful on that. I tried to convert it dataframe

> y_train = pd.DataFrame(y_train)

But it shows the following error:

> ValueError: A target array with shape (15, 1) was passed for an output
> of shape (None, 5)

I also tried to change every list into series than put into a dataframe but that also failed.
Is there any optimal way to get rid of this issue ?

Comment: What are you using to create your network? Try converting your y to 15x5 numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to a numpy array by first casting it to a list:

```
np.array(list(target_comb_list))
```

Then, if necessary, you can convert that to a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(list(target_comb_list)))
```

Comment: I think `DataFrame.explode` might be useful here.

Comment: @Robby : I tried to change the whole series into a np.array and then to a dataframe. I also tried to change every elements of the series (which is actually "list") into a np array and then to a df. But both of the cases it failed.

Comment: What happened? I tried the above code, and it works fine on data with similar structure to yours.

Comment: It shows the same error with shape. Then I used `DataFrame.explode` and then reshaped it. Now it is working.